# Postgis TopologyException: side location conflict at 226.001 39.5158, what's the problem?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

after st_union() PgSQL returns a note:

```
NOTE:  TopologyException: side location conflict at 226.001 39.5158
```

And in the results there are two rows with empty geometry and other rows are ok.
What causes that problem? How to solve it?

Comment: ST_MakeValid solved this for me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I've found the problem. It was a self intersecting polygon.
I used [`ST_IsValidReason`](http://postgis.refractions.net/docs/ST_IsValidReason.html) to find it.

Answer (score 13):

The solution arrived in PostGIS 2.0, ST_IsValid() and ST_MakeValid(). You can ask PostGIS to fix broken geometries. You must be careful with it tough it the source geometry's integrity is important for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

Googling found this related post: http://lists.refractions.net/pipermail/jts-devel/2009-March/002939.html

So it seems your features may be suffering from rounding errors, and it may be solvable by cleaning up the geometry a bit.

It might be worth creating a minimum reproducible case, and post a message on the postgis mailing list.